# Disable sorting for a particular column in jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

I am using the jQuery [DataTables plugin](https://www.datatables.net/) to sort the table fields. My question is: how do I disable sorting for a particular column? I have tried with the following code, but it did not work:

```
"aoColumns": [
  { "bSearchable": false },
  null
]
```

I have also tried the following code:

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
  {
    "bSearchable": false,
    "aTargets": [ 1 ]
  }
]
```

but this still did not produce the desired results.

Comment: I've edited my answer, with an option where you can set the disable columns in your TH definition.

Comment: Disable button using css. check out this page. 
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/21164/disable-sorting-of-one-column#Comment_66660

Comment: you may also want to look https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/05/20/jquery-datatables-turn-off-sorting-of-a-particular-column/

Answer (score 180):

This is what you're looking for:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
      "aoColumnDefs": [
          { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 1 ] }
       ]
});
```

Comment: this worked for me. If you want to sort first column, 'aTargets': [ -1 ], for second 'aTargets': [ 1 ], for third 'aTargets': [ 2 ] and so on.

Comment: you can simply do 'aTargets': [ 1, 2 ]

Comment: @Lasang - Did you really mean `[-1]`, then `[1]`, `[2]`, etc?  What does the `-1` mean?  Doesn't indexing for columns begin at `1` for dataTables?

Comment: `-1` is the index counting from the end of the table. ( `-1` is the last column of the table )

Comment: As of DataTables 1.10.5 it is now possible to define initialisation options using HTML5 data-* attributes. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32281113/1430996

Comment: @wildehahn Wildehahn - I need your help, your solution does not work on first column when I use 0 "zero" in array as you suggested. `"aoColumnDefs": [
                { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [0,1,6] }
            ],`. kindly suggest how to solve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 95):

> As of DataTables 1.10.5 it is now possible to define initialisation
>   options using HTML5 data-* attributes.

-from [DataTables example - HTML5 data-* attributes - table options](https://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-options.html)

So you can use `data-orderable="false"` on the `th` of the column you don't want to be sortable. For example, the second column "Avatar" in the table below will not be sortable:

```
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" data-page-length="25">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th data-orderable="false">Avatar</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8edcff60cdcca2ad650758fa524d4990?s=64&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG" alt="" style="width: 64px; height: 64px; visibility: visible;"></td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/98fe9834dcca2ad650758fa524d4990?s=64&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG" alt="" style="width: 64px; height: 64px; visibility: visible;"></td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        ...[ETC]...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

See [a working example at https://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/6yxvxt7L/](https://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/6yxvxt7L/).

Comment: IMO, this is the best answer here, simplest and most elegant approach

Comment: This disables the sort functionality, but I found (in 1.10.12) that the column is still sorted by default when the DataTable is initialized, which styles the column with an ascending sort glyph. If you don't want this, you can initialize the datatable without sorting like so: $('#example').DataTable({ 'order': [] });

Comment: @BrianMerrell   Wellllllll...look at that! https://jsfiddle.net/ja0ty8xr/  You should open a GitHub issue for that behavior. :)

Answer (score 64):

To make a first column sorting disable, try with the below code in datatables jquery. The null represents the sorting enable here.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "aoColumns": [
  { "bSortable": false },
  null,
  null,
  null
  ]
} );
```

[Disable Sorting on a Column in jQuery Datatables](http://www.craiglotter.co.za/2010/04/19/how-to-disable-sorting-on-a-column-in-jquery-datatables-plugin/)

Comment: @Paulraj The link is broken, would you mind changing it?

Comment: As of DataTables 1.10.5 it is now possible to define initialisation options using HTML5 data-* attributes. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32281113/1430996

Answer (score 61):

Using Datatables 1.9.4 I've disabled the sorting for the first column with this code:

```
/* Table initialisation */
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rules').dataTable({
        "sDom" : "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
        "sPaginationType" : "bootstrap",
        "oLanguage" : {
            "sLengthMenu" : "_MENU_ records per page"
        },
        // Disable sorting on the first column
        "aoColumnDefs" : [ {
            'bSortable' : false,
            'aTargets' : [ 0 ]
        } ]
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

You can disable even by using the `no-sort` class on your `<th>`,

and use this initialization code:

```
// Disable sorting on the no-sort class
"aoColumnDefs" : [ {
    "bSortable" : false,
    "aTargets" : [ "no-sort" ]
} ]
```

**EDIT 2**

In this example I'm using Datables with Bootstrap, following an old blog post. Now there is one link with updated material about [styling Datatables with bootstrap](http://datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap).

Comment: @larrylampco I've updated the post with updated links.

Comment: Thanks.. what about loss of css when we apply sorting

Comment: As of DataTables 1.10.5 it is now possible to define initialisation options using HTML5 data-* attributes. See stackoverflow.com/a/32281113/1430996

Comment: Thanks @paulo, Paulo but I am not able to remove sorting feature from first column of datatable while I have tried with 0 "zero" and "-1" values. any suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

What I use is just add a custom attribute in thead td and control sorting by checking that attr value automatically.

So the HTML code will be

```
<table class="datatables" cellspacing="0px" >

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td data-bSortable="true">Requirements</td>
            <td>Test Cases</td>
            <td data-bSortable="true">Automated</td>
            <td>Created On</td>
            <td>Automated Status</td>
            <td>Tags</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
```

And JavaScript for initializing datatables will be
(it will dynamically get the sorting information from table iteself ;)

```
$('.datatables').each(function(){
    var bFilter = true;
    if($(this).hasClass('nofilter')){
        bFilter = false;
    }
    var columnSort = new Array; 
    $(this).find('thead tr td').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('data-bSortable') == 'true') {
            columnSort.push({ "bSortable": true });
        } else {
            columnSort.push({ "bSortable": false });
        }
    });
    $(this).dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bFilter": bFilter,
        "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
        },
        "aoColumns": columnSort
    });
});
```

Comment: You should use `data-bSortable` instead of `bSortable`. `bSortable` isn't a valid HTML attribute.

Comment: As of DataTables 1.10.5 it is now possible to define initialisation options using HTML5 data-* attributes. See stackoverflow.com/a/32281113/1430996

Answer (score 15):

`columnDefs` now accepts a class. I'd say this is the preferred method if you'd like to specify columns to disable in your markup:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th class="datatable-nosort">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    ...
</table>
```

Then, in your JS:

```
$("table").DataTable({
    columnDefs: [{
        targets: "datatable-nosort",
        orderable: false
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is what you can use to disable certain column to be disabled:

```
 $('#tableId').dataTable({           
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id"},
                { "data": "sampleSortableColumn" },
                { "data": "otherSortableColumn" },
                { "data": "unsortableColumn", "orderable": false}
           ]
});
```

So all you have to do is add the "orderable": false to the column you don't want to be sortable.

Answer (score 6):

```
$("#example").dataTable(
  {
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
      "bSortable": false, 
      "aTargets": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }]
  }
);
```

Comment: Bhavesh's answer is clever, but overkill. To disable sorting simply use abhinav's answer. Disabling sorting on the first column add a column target in the aoColumnDefs option:
`"bSortable": false, "aTargets": [0]`

Answer (score 5):

For Single column sorting disable try this example :

```
<script type="text/javascript">                         
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $("#example").dataTable({
           "aoColumnDefs": [
              { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 0 ] }
           ]
        });
    });                                         
</script>
```

For Multiple columns try this example: you just need to add column number. By default it's starting from 0

```
<script type="text/javascript">                         
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $("#example").dataTable({
           "aoColumnDefs": [
              { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 0,1,2,4,5,6] }
           ]
        });
    });                                         
</script>
```

Here only `Column 3` works

Answer (score 5):

As of **1.10.5**, simply include

> 'orderable: false'

in columnDefs and target your column with

> 'targets: [0,1]'

Table should like like:

```
var table = $('#data-tables').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [{
        targets: [0],
        orderable: false
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you set the FIRST column `orderable` property to false, you **must** also set the default `order` column otherwise it won't work since first column is the default ordering column. Example below disables sorting on first column but sets second column as default order column (remember dataTables' indexes are zero based).

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "order": [[1, 'asc']],
  "columnDefs": [
    { "orderable": false, "targets": 0 }
  ]
} );
```

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me as of July 17, 2020

Answer (score 4):

To update Bhavish's answer (which I think is for an older version of DataTables and didn't work for me).  I think they changed the attribute name.  Try this:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td data-sortable="false">Requirements</td>
        <td data-sortable="false">Automated</td>
        <td>Created On</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
```

Comment: This seems like a nice approach... if it worked, but it doesn't for me.  Is it documented?

Comment: @AllInOne: yes, for `data-orderable`...see http://stackoverflow.com/a/32281113/1430996 . `data-sortable` also works, but I cannot find where it is documented.

Comment: much better solution

Answer (score 3):

```
"aoColumnDefs" : [   
{
  'bSortable' : false,  
  'aTargets' : [ 0 ]
}]
```

Here `0` is the index of the column, if you want multiple columns to be not sorted, mention column index values seperated by `comma(,)`

Comment: is it possible to disable the sorting for all the columns?

Comment: Yes it possible, you can visit this link to know https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/08/18/jquery-datatables-disable-sorting-for-all-columns/#more-1054

Comment: Thanks @coder, but I am not able to remove sorting feature from first column of datatable while I have tried with 0 "zero" and "-1" values. any suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using class:

```
<table  class="table table-datatable table-bordered" id="tableID">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="nosort"><input type="checkbox" id="checkAllreInvitation" /></th>
            <th class="sort-alpha">Employee name</th>
            <th class="sort-alpha">Send Date</th>
            <th class="sort-alpha">Sender</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="userUid[]" value="{user.uid}" id="checkAllreInvitation" class="checkItemre validate[required]" /></td>
            <td>Alexander Schwartz</td>
            <td>27.12.2015</td>
            <td>dummy@email.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tableID').DataTable({
            'iDisplayLength':100,
            "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
            'aoColumnDefs': [{
                'bSortable': false,
                'aTargets': ['nosort']
            }]
        });
    });
</script>
```

> Now you can give "nosort" class to <TH>

Answer (score 2):

This works for me for a single column

```
 $('#example').dataTable( {
"aoColumns": [
{ "bSortable": false 
 }]});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have to hide Some columns, like I hide last name column. I just had to concatenate fname , lname , So i made query but hide that column from front end. The modifications in Disable sorting in such situation are :

```
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 3 ] },
        {
            "targets": [ 4 ],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": true
        }
    ],
```

Notice that I had Hiding functionality here

```
    "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [ 4 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": true
            }
        ],
```

Then I merged it into `"aoColumnDefs"`

Comment: Thanks @Pratik, but I am not able to remove sorting feature from first column of datatable while I have tried with 0 "zero" and "-1" values. any suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the following code to disable ordering on first column:

   ```
   $('#example').dataTable( {
     "columnDefs": [
       { "orderable": false, "targets": 0 }
     ]
   } );
   ```
2. To disable default ordering, you can also use:

   ```
   $('#example').dataTable( {
        "ordering": false, 
   } );
   ```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways, one is defined in html when you define table headers

```
<thead>
  <th data-orderable="false"></th>
</thead>
```

Another way is using javascript, for example, you have table

```
<table id="datatables">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="testid input">test id</th>
            <th class="testname input">test name</th>
    </thead>
</table>
```

then,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datatables').DataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": [ 0], // 0 indicates the first column you define in <thead>
            "searchable": false
        }
        , {
            // you can also use name to get the target column
            "targets": 'testid', // name is the class you define in <th>
            "searchable": false
        }
        ]
    }
    );
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use negative index like this:

```
$('.datatable').dataTable({
    "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ -1 ] }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Nurul, but I am not able to remove sorting feature from first column of datatable while I have tried with 0 "zero" and "-1" values. any suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code will look like this:

```
$(".data-cash").each(function (index) {
  $(this).dataTable({
    "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "oLanguage": {
      "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page",
      "oPaginate": {
        "sPrevious": "Prev",
        "sNext": "Next"
      }
    },
    "bSort": false,
    "aaSorting": []
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer !

`targets` is the column number, it starts from 0

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { "orderable": false, "targets": 0 }
  ]
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directry use .notsortable() method on column

```
 vm.dtOpt_product = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
                .withOption('responsive', true)
        vm.dtOpt_product.withPaginationType('full_numbers');
        vm.dtOpt_product.withColumnFilter({
            aoColumns: [{
                    type: 'null'
                }, {
                    type: 'text',
                    bRegex: true,
                    bSmart: true
                }, {
                    type: 'text',
                    bRegex: true,
                    bSmart: true
                }, {
                    type: 'text',
                    bRegex: true,
                    bSmart: true
                }, {
                    type: 'select',
                    bRegex: false,
                    bSmart: true,
                    values: vm.dtProductTypes
                }]

        });

        vm.dtColDefs_product = [
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0), DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(1),
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(2), DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(3).withClass('none'),
            DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(4), DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(5).notSortable()
        ];
```

Answer (score -2):

set class "no-sort" in th of the table
then add css 
.no-sort { pointer-events: none !important; cursor: default !important;background-image: none !important; }
by this it will hide the arrow updown and disble event in the head.