# How to simply sort by the last column of datatable

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatable

I'm really really new to dataTable, and I just need one simple solution:

```
var initBasicTable = function() {

    var table = $('#basicTable');

    var settings = {
        "sDom": "t",
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "destroy": true,
        "paging": false,
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "order": [[0,'desc']]
    };

    table.dataTable(settings);
    $('#basicTable input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass('selected');
        } else {
            $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('selected');
        }

    });

}
```

This is working, for sorting the first column by default.

But I read that changing the `0` in `"order": [[0,'desc']]` into negative number will begin sorting from the columns on the right. However this:

```
var settings = {
        "sDom": "t",
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "destroy": true,
        "paging": false,
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "order": [[-1,'desc']]
};
```

Throws an error and I have no idea where to continue.

I know dataTable is really powerful and that but, 
[this is no what I was looking for but plenty already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008545/disable-sorting-on-last-column-when-using-jquery-datatables)

Nothing for 'Sort by last(-1) column'? I felt lost. anyone?

Comment: Can you specify the last columns index? I.e. if you have 5 columns then it would be 4

Comment: I must have got the idea from reading [aoColumnDefs](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns), I thought [-1] would work since it is acceptable by 'aTarget'. I would want it to always sort the 'last column' no matter on which table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the re-draw function from dataTables:

```
table.order([0, 'desc']).draw();
```

And don't use the negative values for the column index. just use the positive ones. 
Here in [the api](https://datatables.net/reference/api/order%28%29) there is no mention about the negative column indexes for orderable column.

If you can't follow me right now, read: "https://datatables.net/reference/api/order%28%29"

Comment: I got the idea of negative values from [here](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns) `a negative integer - column index counting from the right`. I know it's not stated in the doc but - why not? If 'aTarget' accepts negative number, generally I would think that 'order' should be the same, right? Otherwise if I apply the script on every page, where tables are shown with different columns, I can't use one script to just sort by the last column.

Comment: alright, then... which version of dataTables.net are you using in your project?

Comment: as you can see that your link in the comment is for older versions than 1.10 you need to use the options provided in the new api

Comment: Or use: $('#example').dataTable( {
    "order": [[ 0, 'asc' ], [ 1, 'asc' ]]
} );

But than you'll have to prove the positive column index

Answer (score 10):

It turned out not so hard, with a bit of work around:

```
var table = $('#basicTable');
    var index = $(table).find('th:last').index();
    var settings = {
        "sDom": "t",
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "destroy": true,
        "paging": false,
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "order": [
            [index, "desc"]
        ]
    };
```

This will get the index of the last 'column' and sort on it first. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 5):

You can initialize the table like this to sort it by last column

```
$('.table').DataTable().columns(-1).order('desc').draw();
```

for details check [this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/29838/anyone-initializing-datatables-to-sort-by-the-last-column)