# How to remove sorting option from DataTables?

Tags: jquery-plugins, datatables

I'm using [DataTables plugin](http://datatables.net/). I don't want to use the sorting option (to sort the columns in ASC or DESC order) which comes by default on each `<thead>`. How can I remove that sorting icon?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable sorting for a particular column in jQuery DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932587/disable-sorting-for-a-particular-column-in-jquery-datatables)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Very similar to @ravisolanki07 , it's just a different way to achieve this.

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ] }, 
        { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ] }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Thx for specifying indexes

Answer (score 118):

In the new `version 1.10` of `jQuery DataTables` you must use [`ordering`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ordering) option to disable ordering on the entire table:

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
    "ordering": false
});
```

Comment: I cannot see in the documentation that ordering *must* be used globally and that ordering does not disappear if it is set individually to all columns. However, the answer seems to be correct. If I set each column to `"ordering": false`, then the sort symbol remains on the first column, even if it doesn't work. At least for me (DataTables Version 1.10.20).

Comment: I confirm this works in `angular 2+` also.  `dtOptions: DataTables.Settings {ordering: false,}`

Answer (score 23):

You can also pass the option on the table itself using data attributes.

```
<table
   data-paging="false"
   data-searching="false"
   data-ordering="false"
>
```

The same principle applies to column headers.

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>I'm sortable</th>
    <th data-orderable="false">I'm not sortable</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

But, I came across a situation where I wanted to remove all columns sorting and realize that Datatable still adds the icon on the first column when using a `th data-orderable="false"` on all columns, in that case, use the `data-ordering` on the table instead.

This can be handy should you use the same custom script to generate all your Datatables.

Comment: it works very well for one column instead of all table

Answer (score 16):

Ok, so, the answers here are a bit old. So I thought I could provide e newer answer:

[source documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs)

As of 2018, the way to achieve this, per field, is:

```
$('#id-of-my-table').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [
        { "orderable": false, "targets": [0, 4, 5, 6] },
        { "orderable": true, "targets": [1, 2, 3] }
    ]
});
```

As you can see, targets accepts an array of column indexes.

Comment: You can even omit the orderable true part and just state which ones to disable sorting on.

Comment: This works for me. Just need to put orderable false. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to disable the default sorting but keep the columns sortable, just use the following configuration :

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "aaSorting": []
    });
})
```

Comment: This is what I was searching for. tnx

Comment: Exactly what i wanted to archieve

Answer (score 8):

There are 2 ways you can try.

First, try setting "bSort" to false.
Note that, this will disable sorting all around.

`$('#jTable').dataTable({ "bSort" : false } );`

Second, try setting aaSorting to empty.
Note that, this will remove sorting for specific column.
`$('#jTable').dataTable({ "aaSorting" : [[]] });`

Let us know if either works for you.
Hope it helps,

Kashif Solangi

Answer (score 3):

Using the `aoColumns` attribute, sorting a specific column can be easily controlled. An example is given bellow:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
oTable = jQuery('#DataTables_Table_0').dataTable( {           
            "bDestroy": true,
            "bAutoWidth": true,  
            "bFilter": true,
            "bSort": true, 
            "aaSorting": [[0]],         
            "aoColumns": [
                { "bSortable": false },
                { "bSortable": true },
                { "bSortable": true },
                { "bSortable": true },
                { "bSortable": true },
                { "bSortable": true },
                { "bSortable": false }
            ]   
        } );
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

->  for removing sorting in particular column then use **orderable: false**

->  for removing search from particular column then use **searchable:
false**

```
 $('#table-name').DataTable({
            "columns": [
                   {"data": "column_name"},
                   {"data": "column_name" , orderable: false},
                   {"data": "column_name"},
                   {"data": "column_name" , orderable: false},
                   {"data": "action"}
                  ],
                  aoColumnDefs: [
                    {
                       bSortable: false,
                       aTargets: [ -1 ]
                    }
                 ]
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it by `bSortable` to `false` in `aocolumn` like :

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "aoColumns": [
        { "sType": "html","bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false },
        { "sType": "html" },
        { "sType": "html", "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false },
        { "sType": "html" },
        { "sType": "html","bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false },
        { "sType": "html" },
        { "sType": "html" },
        { "sType": "html" },
        { "sType": "date-euro" }
    ]
});
```

You can also exclude from search by set `bSearchable` to `false`

Answer (score 0):

Old question but none of these answers worked for me since none of them prevented the sort on click and I didn't want to reinitialize, so I'll post my solution:

Basically, clone the header, removing the `sorting` class from the `<th>` cells, insert clone after real header and hide the original. When you want to reenable, just reshow original header and remove clone.

This worked for my case, you may have to adjust the `thead` selector you use depending on your setup.

```
// grab the header
const stashedHeader = $('.dataTable thead');
// copy it and remove sorting class from the copy's th cells
const nosortClone = stashedHeader.clone();
nosortClone.find('th').removeClass('sorting');
// hide original and insert clone after it
stashedHeader.hide().after(nosortClone);

...
// re-enable
stashedHeader.show()
nosortClone.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the other answers only deal with initial settings. I needed to disable sorting afterward via javascript based on user action.

If you pass in options to the DataTable function then it will fail because it has already been initialized. If you don't pass a parameter, then it will retrieve the current settings, and you can manipulate the existing settings.

```
$('#example').DataTable().settings()[0].aoColumns.forEach(function(c) { 
    // could use c.nTh to get the actual th element if needed
    c.bSortable = false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply you can use this

```
"ordering": false,
```

**Full Code:**

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "ordering": false,
 });
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of the currently highest-voted answer from 2016 by Ricardo Rivera Nieves