# Modify Bootstrap DataTable

Tags: symfony, sorting, templates, datatable, adapt

I used an example of bootstrap datatable to have a sortable table on my symfony project. I use datatables.net

With this javascript code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datatable').DataTable();
} );
```

And my table in HTML :

```
<table id="datatable" class="table table-striped">
 <thead>
    <tr>...
```

The only problem is that I don't want all my columns to be sortable (some columns only contain a checkbox or a button for example). Moreover with this table and this javascript code I automatically have a search bar as well as Previous Next buttons and other options that appear automatically. I would like to be able to modify this default template by removing all these options that I don't need. Do you have an idea how to adapt this datatable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335928/how-to-remove-sorting-option-from-datatables Might help you. Or directly into the DataTables doc: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs

Comment: Yes I found It thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read documentation for datatables. https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/examples/initialisation/restrictedOrdering.html

Example:

```
// add class reorder on column, that you want to order
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        rowReorder: true,
        columnDefs: [
            { orderable: true, className: 'reorder', targets: 0 },
            { orderable: false, targets: '_all' }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I found the solution in this part of the documentation