# Working with column IDs using datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable and I would like to know how I can make certain columns with specific ids NOT SORTABLE. I have an if statement which I'm sure I will need started however I'm not sure what should be placed inside the if statement. How is this accomplished? I am unable to find this in the `Datatables` documentation.

http://datatables.net/usage/columns

```
/* DataTables */
if ($('.dynamicTable').size() > 0)
{
    $('.dynamicTable').dataTable({
        if ()
        {
            { "bSortable": false },
        }
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What? Please do a grammar check on this.

Comment: Corrected. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [disable a column sorting using datatables of jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932587/disable-a-column-sorting-using-datatables-of-jquery)

Comment: There's a problem with this though. I've doing this as a global code. So not all tables are going to have the same first column or what not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the following syntax.

```
$('.dynamicTable').dataTable({
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
        "bSortable" : false,
        "aTargets" : [ "checkth", "labelth", "actionsth" ]
    }]
});
```