# how to avoid a column from sorting in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using jquery datatable, I want avoid a column while sorting other columns, that is that column should remain static.

Comment: Can you give an example of the result of this sort?

Comment: I hope this might help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4672946/4672534

Comment: @rmondesilva  this is for disable sorting a particular column, while sorting other columns it will affect. My requirement is that column should not be change, i should remain same

Answer (score 0):

Use "orderFixed". Read https://datatables.net/reference/option/orderFixed

**"orderFixed": [ *column index*, *sort* ];**

```
$('#tbl').DataTable({
                "orderFixed": [ 0, 'asc' ]
          });
```

Comment: it is not working. while sorting other columns the value inside fixed column also affected

Comment: It works on mine. I think it's better if you will also post your codes. So we can see the problem clearly why it does not work.