# How to disable sorting in DataTables at the page load only?

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatable

I use  this code for run DataTable on my table . This worked currently but I want run DataTable  on my table with out sorting. Now my table sorted by column 0 .

How to do this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7659254/842112

Comment: Possible duplicate of [disable a column sorting using jquery datatables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932587/disable-a-column-sorting-using-jquery-datatables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you need something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
    "bSort" :false
});
});
```

and if you wish to disable sorting column wise, You can use this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myTable').DataTable( {
     "aoColumns": [
     { "bSortable": false },
     null,
    null,
    null
    ]
   });
});
```

Comment: @programmer138200 You can check this. Let me know, if it works for you.

Comment: OK. This worked.Now after load table rows display with out sorting. This is right  but I want sort by columns after loading .Is this possible?

Comment: @programmer138200 If i am getting you right. Initially, you want sorting disabled for empty table and when datatable is filled after pageload, you want to enable sorting again, right?

Comment: I want after page load my table created with out sorting.I sort via  the server side code. and I want sorting option enable for me