# How to disable sorting on a column in a datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, datatable

I'm trying to disable the sorting function on one of my columns.
I already have tried multiple things but these didn't work.
I tried adding this:  `data-sorter="false"` to my `<th>` but it just ignored it.
I also have tried this but it also just ignored it:

```
“columnDefs”: [ {
“targets”: 2,
“orderable”: false
}]
```

When I tried these methods I did not get any errors.
I also found out using inspect element that my `<th>` automatically gets the class `sorting` added to it.
Here is my code:
**My table:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
 <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Vraag</th>
            <th>Gepost op</th>
            <th>Acties</th>// I want to disable sorting here
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**My js:**

```
// Call the dataTables jQuery plugin
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dataTable').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [ {
      "targets": 2,
      "orderable": false
    } ]
  });
});
```

Please help me I have been searching for an answer the last 3 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to set  `"bSort":false`?  For more details see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4672946/5813861)

---

**Disable Sort from datatable** 
 `"bSort":false`

---

**To Disable sorting on particular column:**

`"bSortable": false`

---

**More specific:**

```
  $('#table').dataTable( {
    "bSort":true,
     aoColumnDefs: [
       { aTargets: [ '_all' ], bSortable: false },
       { aTargets: [ 0 ], bSortable: true },
       { aTargets: [ 1 ], bSortable: true }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: This works except my second column also has disabled sorting now https://prnt.sc/l15qaw